# How to checkout specific product from cms page magento 2?

Tags: checkout, cms-pages, magento-2.1.8

I have a virtual product and want to add to the cart when clicking on a button which is on cms page.

Customer must be redirected to checkout page after clicking on the button.

Comment: This module may help you: https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-buynow

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have done without it.

Comment: You can also post your answer on your own question to help other developers :).